# Error in switch convert in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, loops, switch-statement

I have array of arrays - `var days: [[Int]] = [[1], [1,2,3], [7]]`
and I'd like to convert `Int` into name by `String` and add it at new array `arrayOfStringDays`. My code:

```
var days: [[Int]] = [[1], [1,2,3], [7]]    
var arrayOfStringDays = [[String]]() 

            for i in 0..<days.count {

                switch days[i] {
                    case [1]:
                        arrayOfStringDays.append(["one"])
                    case [1,2,3]:
                        arrayOfStringDays.append(["one, two, three"])
                    case [7]:
                        arrayOfStringDays.append(["seven"])
                    default:
                        break
                } 
            }
```

but I see error near every case:

> Expression pattern of type '[Int]' cannot match values of type '[Int]'

in what is my mistake? thanks!

Comment: Your problem has been solved in Swift 4.1 / Xcode 9.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about exact error, but you can do conversion of [[Int]] something like this.

```
var days: [[Int]] = [[1], [1,2,3], [7]]

let numberStr = ["Zero","One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine"]

let daysInString = days.map { (intList) -> [String] in
    return intList.map({ (intValue) -> String in
        return numberStr[intValue]
    })
}
print(daysInString)

// Output : [["One"], ["One", "Two", "Three"], ["Seven"]]
```

Answer (score 4):

**Update:** Conditional conformance has been implemented Swift 4.1,
and in particular arrays (and some other collection types) conform
to `Equatable`  if their elements do.

Your code now compiles without problems in Xcode 9.3.

---

The `switch` statement uses the "pattern-match" operator

```
public func ~=<T : Equatable>(a: T, b: T) -> Bool
```

to compare the given value against the various cases.
The problem is that `Array` does not conform to
`Equatable`, even if the array elements are `Equatable`.
(This is going to change with Swift 4, see
[SE-0143 Conditional conformances](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0143-conditional-conformances.md).)

May I suggest a different solution?
A nested `map` to convert the nested array, and a number formatter
with "spell-out" style to convert numbers to words:

```
let days: [[Int]] = [[1], [1,2,3], [7]]

let formatter = NumberFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.numberStyle = .spellOut

let arrayOfStringDays = days.map {
    $0.map { formatter.string(from: $0 as NSNumber) ?? String($0) }
}

print(arrayOfStringDays)
// [["one"], ["one", "two", "three"], ["seven"]]
```

You can also set the formatter locale to a different language, 
or use the default value to get the result in the user's default
language. Example:

```
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "ru")
// ...
print(arrayOfStringDays)
// [["один"], ["один", "два", "три"], ["семь"]]
```